# Real-world examples of perverse sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory

If I were to have asked this question about local systems, it would be extremely easy to give examples from physics/biology, etc. I can give example if people want, but this should be easy to Google.

**Question:** What examples of *perverse sheaves* naturally show up in nature?

---

More specifically, I mean examples which are not local systems, and the example only applies to perverse sheaves (or constructible complexes of sheaves) and not sheaves of vector spaces in general.

Comment: I don't know if theoretical physics counts, but I think that perverse sheaves have applications in string theory. Also perverse sheaves feature in the geometric Langlands program, which is also (maybe only conjecturally, I don't know much about this) related to theoretical physics.

Comment: If it is string theory , it does not count.